# How fast does the faster athlete run?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Two athletes at the same position on a circular 4-mile race track start running. If they run in opposite directions, they meet in 12 minutes. How ever, it takes one hour for the faster runner to gain a lap if they run in the same direction. How fast, in miles per hour, does the faster athlete run?

This is the explanation to the answer provided by the book:

---

Let $x$ and $y$ be the speed of the faster athlete and slower athlete in mules per hour, respectively. Two athletes meet in 12 minutes or ($\frac{1}{5}$ hr) is 4 miles. This can be written as

$$\frac{x}{5}+\frac{y}{5}=4\Rightarrow x+y=20$$

It takes one hour for the faster athlete to gain a lap if both athletes run n the same directions, which means that the difference of the distances that they run is 4 miles. This can be written as

### $$x-y=4$$

The explanation continues to solving the system and eventually get $x=12$. I don't understand the part "...which means the difference of the distances they run is 4 miles...". Why is that? and why the same variables when it says those represent the speed of the two athletes?

Answer (score 1):

The faster runner runs 4 miles further than the slower runner because the problem states that the faster runner has gained a lap on the slower runner (i.e. that the runner has completed an enter extra [4 mile] lap more than the slower runner).  They "use the same variables" because it takes 1 hour for that to happen, so $1x-1y=x-y$.

Comment: so does that mean by the time the faster runner has run for an hour, it actually ran an extra 4 miles, which means 4 miles farther than the slower one? Is that why the difference between their distances should be 4?

Comment: @harpey1111 yes, that's it.